# Using 64 bit wuauclt from 32 bit command prompt

Tags: windows-server-2008, scripting, 64-bit

I have a script that for legacy reasons needs to run inside a 32 bit command shell. This script also includes references to certain core windows binaries - most notably wuauclt but others as well - which are not accessible by default within the 32 bit environment.

This script is being run in several locations including many windows 7 and server 2008 r2 boxes.

I'm aware of the possibility to copy files from the system32 to syswow64 in order to get around this. Is there any better method - something along the lines of adding an entry to the path variable - which will allow me to fall back to these 64 bit binaries from within a 32 bit script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to reference the 64-bit `wuauclt.exe` as `%SystemRoot%\sysnative\wuauclt.exe` from your 32-bit `cmd.exe` process.

Comment: Thanks Evan, perfect. Is there any drawback in adding this path to to the %path variable? It looks like should theoretically work and I'm not coming up with any down sides.

Comment: Personally, I'd be explicit in my references just to be safe. I tend not to make a lot of assumptions about the system in my scripts, though.